# A question about the quotient group $GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is that : Is $GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$ isomorphic to $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ ? If yes, how can one prove it ?

I was thinking in this direction : Given any arbitrary matrix $A$ in $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, $det(A)=\eta\neq0$. Now In the quotient group $GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$, the matrices $A$ and $A.(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\eta}}I)$ are the same, hence $\forall A\in GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$, $det(A)=1$ Therefore $$GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}\cong PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$$ **But this does not seem correct**, because I could have said : in $GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$, the matrices $A$ and $A.(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\eta}}I)$ are the same, hence $\forall A\in GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\lambda I\}$, $det(A)=\frac{1}{2}$

I am confused here...
I already appreciate your helpful comments/answers about the question itself AND the way I looked at at it.

Comment: Find a surjective map $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf C) \to \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf C)$ such that the kernel of this map is exactly $\{\lambda I\}$. You are on the right track, but the issue is that the determinant map defined in the usual way does not make sense. This is simply because you can't define the determinant of something in the quotient to be the determinant of an arbitrary lift to $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf C)$, otherwise there are several possible determinants (in fact, all nonzero values are possible).

Comment: What does "quotient space" mean? Are you talking about quotient *groups*?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes ! I mean that , and I will fix it now

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct. the only problem is that you have embellished it with some false/meaningless statements. You just have to prove that for any matrix $A \in {\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb C})$, theere is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $\det( \lambda A) = 1$, and you have done that. Incidentally the equivalent statement is true in all dimensions - there is nothing special about dimension $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$. We define $PGL(n,\mathbf{C})$ to be the quotient groupe of $GL(n,\mathbf{C})$ by its center $Z_1$. We define $PSL(n,\mathbf{C})$ to be the quotient group of $SL(n,\mathbf{C})$ by its center $Z_2$.

By definition $Z_1$ is the set of elements of $GL(n,\mathbf{C})$ commuting to all matrices of $GL(n,\mathbf{C})$. If two matrices $A$ and $B$ commute, the eigenspaces of $A$ are stable by $B$. Therefore an element of $Z_1$ leaves stable any eigenspace of any element of $GL(n,\mathbf{C})$, *a fortiori* any line of $\mathbf{C}^2$. It is well-known that an endomorphism leavin every line stable is an homothety, and our endomorphism being invertible means that our center elements is $\lambda Id$ for $\lambda\in\mathbf{C}^{\times}$. Therefore : $Z_1 = \mathbf{C}^{\times} Id \simeq \mathbf{C}^{\times}$.

By definition $Z_2$ is the set of elements of $SL(n,\mathbf{C})$ commuting to all matrices of $SL(n,\mathbf{C})$. Let $g\in Z_2$ and $h\in GL(n,\mathbf{C})$. Let $\zeta$ a $n$-root of $det(g)$ and $h_2 := \frac{1}{\zeta} h$. Then $det(h_2) = 1$, showing that $h_2 \in SL(n,\mathbf{C})$. Then $g$ commutes to $h_2$, which implies that $g$ commutes to $h$ also. Therefore $Z_2 \subseteq Z_1$. This shows that $Z_2 = \mathbf{U}_n Id \simeq \mathbf{U}_n$.

Now consider the obvious inclusion $ i : SL(n,\mathbf{C}) \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbf{C})$ mapping an element $g$ to itself. It is a group morphism. As we have $i(Z_2) \subseteq Z_1$, the morphism $i$ induces a so-called quotient morphism $j : PSL(n,\mathbf{C}) = SL(n,\mathbf{C}) / Z_2 \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbf{C}) / Z_1 = PGL(n,\mathbf{C})$ sending the class of $g \in SL(n,\mathbf{C})$ to the class of $g \in GL(n,\mathbf{C})$. The morphism $j$ is obviously injective.

Now let $\theta$ be an element of $PGL(n,\mathbf{C})$. $\theta$ is the class of an element $g\in GL(n,\mathbf{C})$ modulo $Z_1$. We can write $g = det(g) g_2$ with $g_2 \in SL(n,\mathbf{C})$. Multiply it by $\zeta^{-1} Id \in Z_1$ where $\zeta$ is an $n$-rooth of $1$ and you'll get a matrix $M$ of determinant $1$, whose class modulo $Z_1$ is still $\theta$. Note $\eta$ the class of $M$ modulo $Z_2$. Then, $j(\eta) = \theta$ by construction of $j$.

This shows that the canonical (injective) morphism $j : PSL(n,\mathbf{C}) \rightarrow PGL(n,\mathbf{C})$ is in fact an isomorphism.

Taking $n=2$, you have the answer to your question.

For a general $n$, all remains true is $\mathbf{C}$ is replaced by a commutative field in which each element has an $n$-root.